# Does Noether's theorem show that electric charge (and other charges) are not fundamental? (LAYMEN)

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Just to clarify, I am just a laymen so go easy on me.
I was looking into where electric charge comes from, and apparently it comes from $U(1)$ symmetry. But what does that mean?
Does it mean that electric charge of fundamental particles is a mathematical symmetry and not an intrinsic property? Or am I just confused.

Here's an answer someone gave on the topic of where electric charge comes from.

> Generally, charge can be defined as something that is conserved. According to Noether's theorem, it may be associated to a particular symmetry. In the case of electric charge, it follows from the symmetry action when the wavefunction/field is multiplied by a complex phase $e^{i φ}$, and is sometimes known as a $U(1)$ charge.

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/where-does-charge-come-from.234402/

So charge is not an intrinsic property and is just a consequence of symmetry?

Comment: Charge is an experimental observation, the electron is charged by measuring its interaction with electric and magnetic fields. It is a mathematically successful theory that assigns a U(1) symmetry to explain mathematically the conservation of charge observed experimentally.

Comment: Why would charges being "a consequence of symmetry" mean that they are not "intrinsic fundamental"? "Fundamental" is a very dangerous word because there are very different notions of what it can mean.

Comment: @annav So the whole U(1) symmetry (Noether's theorem) only explain how charged is conserved? Not where it comes from?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is charge a consequence of symmetry?

Comment: @Nov You could say that charge is a consequence of symmetry, but you could also say that symmetry is a consequence of charge. They are, to some extent, the same thing; which is more fundamental is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Nov  symmetry of U(1) is a mathematical model which fits the data and predicts future measurement values. Physics at present is about fitting measurements with a mathematical model  AND the model has to be predictive ( otherwise it is just a mathematical map)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Photons don't have a charge, but still are a part of electromagnetism described by the U(1) symmetry. Thus the symmetry is more fundamental than charge. Furthermore, at the quantum level, there is no charge in the classical sense, but only a quantum number that indicates the ability to emit or absorb photons. It would be unnatural to say that this ability is more fundamental than the U(1) symmetry. Lastly, Noether charges of other symmetries are all very different, but the concept of symmetry is the same for all. So clearly symmetry is a more fundamental concept.

Comment: Every intrinsic property  is a consequence of some symmetry.